# Uninstalling anaconda environment from Mac (M2)

Tags: python, anaconda, conda

I'm trying to uninstall anaconda completely from my system. To do so, I follow instructions mentioned in [Anaconda Documentation](https://docs.anaconda.com/free/anaconda/install/uninstall/) for *Full Uninstall*.

When I run `conda install anaconda-clean`, I get the message -

```
Collecting package metadata (current_repodata.json): done
Solving environment: | 
The environment is inconsistent, please check the package plan carefully
The following packages are causing the inconsistency:

# list of external libraries/packages

failed with initial frozen solve. Retrying with flexible solve.
Solving environment: failed with repodata from current_repodata.json, will retry with next repodata source.
Collecting package metadata (repodata.json): done
Solving environment: - 
The environment is inconsistent, please check the package plan carefully
The following packages are causing the inconsistency:

# list of external libraries/packages (same as above)

done

==> WARNING: A newer version of conda exists. <==
  current version: 4.12.0
  latest version: 23.5.0

Please update conda by running

    $ conda update -n base -c defaults conda

# List of packages that will be UPDATED & DOWNGRADED

Proceed ([y]/n)?
```

When I proceed, I get the error -

```
Preparing transaction: done
Verifying transaction: failed

RemoveError: 'requests' is a dependency of conda and cannot be removed from conda's operating environment.
```

When I try to update `conda` using -  `conda update -n base -c defaults conda` as suggested, I still get the above `RemoveError`.

How can I avoid removing `requests` and still uninstall conda? Any work around or alternative procedure would also be helpful.

Comment: As per duplicate, you don’t have to install it in **base**. You can even just manually remove the files/folder.